# ngSwitch default case not executing

Tags: angular

I want to implement `ngSwitch` in my code like this:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="accessLevel">
    <div class="customer" *ngSwitchCase="ENABLED">
        This is customer data
    </div>
    <div  *ngSwitchDefault> 
        this is default
    </div>
    <div class="customer-blurr" *ngSwitchCase="DISABLED"> 
        This is disabled Customer Data
    </div>
</div>
```

In my case `accessLevel` is undefined and I am expecting `this is default` but it is showing:

```
This is customer data.

This is disabled Customer Data.
```

As I read from [the official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html), if nothing matches it should go to default case. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the value of the `*ngSwitchCase` directive must be the *expression* to match, not the value. In your case, you're presumably wanting to compare to the string `'ENABLED'`, rather than some field with that name, therefore it should be e.g.:

```html
<div class="customer" *ngSwitchCase="'ENABLED'">
                                <!-- ^ note quotes -->
```

You are seeing both the `ENABLED` and `DISABLED` cases because neither of those names are defined, so you're actually matching `undefined == undefined`, which evaluates truthy. The default is therefore not shown, but *both* of the other cases are.

Alternatively, you could define some constants or an enum to compare to, rather than passing around strings, which would improve the semantics of your code.

Comment: Excellent . Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Change your HTML as below :

```html
    <div [ngSwitch]="accessLevel">
        <div class="customer" *ngSwitchCase="'ENABLED'">
          This is customer data
        </div>
        <div  *ngSwitchDefault> 
          this is default
        </div>
        <div class="customer-blurr" *ngSwitchCase="'DISABLED'"> 
          This is disabled Customer Data
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note: you need to add single quotes inside the double quotes so Angular knows it is a string literal rather than a variable.

Comment: Note that it's generally helpful to explain *why* that change should be made.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1 for your effort .